# Cannot parse rss as html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse this rss: https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs?joblist-0-----rss

I try to use BeautifulSoup but I cannot make sense of what is going on. I get the answer

```
82
0
```

when I use the following script.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()

response = session.get('https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs?joblist-0-----rss')

doc = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

titles = doc.find_all('title')

print( len(titles) )

divs = doc.find_all('div')
```

As far as I understand the data is given in html format and there is only one title tag and several divs. What is going on here? I got similar results using pyquery.

Comment: Where does `doc` originate from. Mind that `rss` is not `html`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to make `soup` before using `BeautifulSoup`. 
Add this line - `doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')`

Here is the full code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()
response = session.get('https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs?joblist-0-----rss')
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
titles = doc.find_all('title')

print(titles)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste this line. I have the full script now. The problem is that it finds a lot of titles that do not exist in the html and no divs.

Comment: @tst I think all those `title` actually exist and I don't see any `div` there.

Comment: Ah, yes I am! I used the developer tools of firefox to check the DOM tree and I believed everything it told me...

Comment: It seems I don't :)